# Select2 and initSelection callback

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

On page load, I'm trying to use initSelection to select ID 60 *(specified value of the input field)*. I can't seem to get it to work properly.

The PHP scripts work great and return the correct values, but how do I get the JS to do the callback correctly?

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#editAlbumArtistId').select2({
            placeholder: 'Search names',
            ajax: {
                url: "/jQueryScripts/jQuerySelectListArtists.php",
                dataType: 'json',
                quietMillis: 100,
                data: function (term, page) {
                    return {
                        term: term, //search term
                        page_limit: 10 // page size
                    };
                },
                results: function (data, page) {
                    return {results: data.results};
                }

            },
            initSelection: function(element, callback) {

            var id = $(element).val();
            if(id !== "") {
                $.ajax("/jQueryScripts/jQuerySelectListArtists.php", {
                    data: {id: id},
                    dataType: "json"
                }).done(function(data) {
                    callback(data);
                });
            }
        }
    });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<p>
    <input type='hidden' value="60" data-init-text='Search names' name='editAlbumArtistId' id='editAlbumArtistId' style="width:180px;"/>
</p>
```

Every time I refresh the page, I see that the PHP script gets executed and that it returns the proper ID and text. However, the field isn't updated and I've seriously tried everything I can think of.

I'm using Select2 3.4.3.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried inspecting what happens in developer tools? See if your ajax call is returning a 200, and that the the json has a key of `results` in it.

Comment: You should use ajax settings ( success , error, complete ). http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings

Comment: Why are you putting jsonp as datatype?

Comment: Thanks for the comments so far! I've changed datatype to json from jsonp (didn't know the difference, sorry). I now get "undefined" upon load. I've tried using ajax success, same results. @Wil the ajax is returning 200. The ajax is indeed returning results.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Finally solved it! I figured `select2` didn't want an array since it's a single value, so I selected the first element of the data.results array.

```
callback(data.results[0]);
```

And if you have set multiple:true, just accept the entire results array;

```
callback(data.results);
```

Comment: How do you know this? i got mad because this problem and work 3 days! Finally find you awesome answer!!!

Comment: @mad-marvin It would have been better if you /someone had provided the object structure . Coz its not always obvious about what `data` or `data.results` or even `data.results[0]` contains. I am still looking at `select2` code and update here if I find something.

Comment: Just updated the answer itself. I hope it helps and do not mess up with the actual answer.

Comment: it depends on your remote result. If you result looks like [{...}, {...}], then data[0] is just fine. Mad Marvins result looks probably somehow like this: {"results": [{...}, {...}]}

Answer (score 3):

You could also use this for less code:

```
    initSelection: function(element, callback) {
        return $.getJSON("/jQueryScripts/jQuerySelectListArtists.php?id=" + element.val(), null, function(data) {
            return callback(data[0]);
        });
    }
```

I saw this example in the Select2 wiki, but i had to deal with callback(data) vs callback(data[0]) like you did.